# Is it possible to use an SSD with a Airport Card PCIe slot in a Mac mini (A1176)?

Tags: mac, ssd, pci-express

I have made some modifications to an old Mac mini I picked up. I’ve removed the optical drive and have two 750GB WD drives installed, maxed the RAM and upgraded the CPU to a Core 2 Duo.

Now I’d like to remove the Airport Card from the PCIe slot on the logic board and install an SSD card: [Intel Solid-State Drive 310 Series](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004I5H6FU/ref=s9_simh_gw_p147_d1_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-5&pf_rd_r=0FTY03PK2RWNAHFHXR5Q&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128293&pf_rd_i=468294)

My questions are:

- Will macOS recognize this drive in the PCIe slot?
- Will it be bootable so I can load the OS?
- What data transfer speed is possible?
- Did Apple use a standard PCIe?

The plan is to load the OS on the SSD and have the two 750’s in a RAID 1 configuration as a media array.

I don’t need Bluetooth or Wi-Fi.

Will this work?

Comment: It depends on through what BUS controller the mPCIe is running through

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a standard mini-PCIe slot, though more recent Mac minis don’t have them. I found [an article](http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/systems/mini_esata_card_mod/macmini_estatacard_mod.html) about someone successfully installing a SATA controller in their slot, which certainly sounds positive for your proposal.

Sorry I can’t be more definitive, but there probably aren’t many people doing this! I have a SATA OCZ Vertex 2 in my 2009 Mac mini, and it flies.